In KQL (Kusto Query Language) can I group by a column (Time) and sum all the other columns containing integer?
I want to produce a table that fits the required format for Time Series data visualization in Grafana  Cloud. (more details : https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/time-series)
customEvents
| where name == "send_editionCO_service" and timestamp > datetime("2024-10-25, 8:00:00.000")
| evaluate bag_unpack(customDimensions)
| extend formsData = parse_json(Forms)
| mv-expand formsData
| extend FormCode = formsData.FormLibelle,
         FormLibelle = formsData.FormCode
| extend Time = bin(timestamp, 1h)
| summarize nbForms = count() by Time, EtatCode, EtatLibelle
| project Time, EtatCode, EtatLibelle, nbForms
| order by Time
| extend index = row_number()
| order by EtatCode, index
| extend total=row_cumsum(nbForms, EtatCode != prev(EtatCode))
| evaluate pivot(EtatLibelle, sum(total))
| project-away EtatCode, nbForms, index;

I run this column and get this result.
Result table
I want to group by Time and make a sum on all of the other columns. The output would be a table with only the 4 dates and the n other columns summed.
--> [Time] / [Column 1] / [Column 2] / [Column 3]

Can you provide a datatable statement with some example data?


In KQL (Kusto Query Language) can I group by a column (Time) and sum all the other columns containing integer?

Yes, you can do that using below KQL Query:
If you want for 1 hr:
RithTable
| summarize 
    Colname1 = sum(Colname1), 
    Colname2 = sum(Colname2), 
    ................,
    ................, 
    Colnamex = sum(Colnamex)
by bin(Time, 1h)

For 1 day, change to bin(Time, 1d).
Output( based on your input):

Fiddle.

Thanks for the answer but I think the problem wasn't understood, my communication lacked of precision. The n columns appear after a pivot which means I don't have the actual control over those. It could 3 columns like it could 50 columns. The solution you gave me work if there's n fixed columns with known names. But in my context I don't, I have n columns with different names and I want a some of these dynamic columns by Time.
